# Disable warnings while running appium tests

Tags: python, selenium, appium

```
import unittest

from appium import webdriver


class CheckOutTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        capabilities = {'platformName': 'Android',
                        'platformVersion': '6.0.1',
                        'browserName': 'Chrome',
                        'deviceName': 'Z2 Plus'
                        }
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', capabilities)


    def test_checkout(self):
        "some code here"
```

When I run this code on my android device, this warning is continously generated :

```
/home/avanti/Documents/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py:375: ResourceWarning: unclosed <socket.socket fd=4, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=6, laddr=('127.0.0.1', 55020), raddr=('127.0.0.1', 4723)>
return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
```

What is this warning and how can I disable it. 
My appium server version - 1.8.1, 
apppium python client - 0.28, selenium version - 3.14

Also, what is causing this , is it safe to ignore?

Answer (score 1):

There is a library for dealing with warnings in python

https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html

You're looking for the `filterwarnings` function

Comment: Thanks @user7374610 , but what is the reason for these warnings and is it safe to ignore them?